# Automatically submit a value on click to a form using Javascript/Java in a Django form

Tags: javascript, java, django

I am working on a web app using Django/Python/Javascript/Java.  The focal point is a map of the USA.  A user should be able to click on a region and the value of that region should automatically query a database and return certain information.  Currently, my code produces a const called regionName and the value of regionName is passed automatically as input to the search bar; however, from here a user needs to manually click the 'search' button to submit the form and query the database.  As below:

```
  onRegionClick: function(event, code){
            console.log('event', event, 'code', code);
            const regionName = map.getRegionName(code);
            console.log('regionName', regionName);
            $("#selection").val(regionName);
  
        },

      });
```

What I am trying to do with the code is to automatically submit the value of regionName after it is passed to the search bar.  Efforts thus far have been similar to the code below.

**$("#selection")**   - the form

**$("#q")** - the name of the button

```
 $("#selection").on('change', function(){
                if ($("#selection").val() === regionName ) {
                  $("#q").click();
                }
              });
```

This is not producing any errors, but it's not producing any results either.

I've tried various substitutes along similar lines such as:

.on('input'.. instead of 'change'
.submit() instead of .click()

I've also have an .autocomplete() method I'm using.  I'm not sure if this is causing a conflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
              var states = [
                {% for states in states %}

                " {{states.state}} ",

                {% endfor %}

              ];

              $("#selection").autocomplete({
                  source: states
              }); 

            });

          </script>
```

**Here is the entire index.html page:**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mortgage OpsBot</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{% static 'jquery-jvectormap.css' %}">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'custom.css' %}">
  <script src="{% static 'jquery-1.8.2.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'jquery-jvectormap.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'jquery-mousewheel.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'jvectormap.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'abstract-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'abstract-canvas-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'abstract-shape-element.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'svg-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'svg-group-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'svg-canvas-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'svg-shape-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'svg-path-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'svg-circle-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'svg-image-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'svg-text-element.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'vml-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vml-group-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vml-canvas-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vml-shape-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vml-path-element.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vml-circle-element.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'map-object.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'region.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'marker.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'vector-canvas.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'simple-scale.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'numeric-scale.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'ordinal-scale.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'color-scale.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'data-series.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'proj.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'map.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'multimap.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'jquery-jvectormap-data-us-lcc-en.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'jquery-jvectormap-data-us-fl-lcc-en.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      var map;


      map = new jvm.Map({
        container: $('#map1'),
        maxLevel: 1,
        map: 'us_lcc_en',
        regionsSelectable: true,
        regionsSelectableOne: true,
        regionStyle: {
          initial: {
            fill: '#B8E186'
          },
          selected: {
            fill: '#4e5c6b'

          }
        },


         onRegionSelected: function(){
          if (window.localStorage) {
            window.localStorage.setItem(
              'jvectormap-selected-regions',
              JSON.stringify(map.getSelectedRegions())
            );
   
          }
          
        },
 
          onRegionClick: function(event, code){
            console.log('event', event, 'code', code);
            const regionName = map.getRegionName(code);
            console.log('regionName', regionName);
            $("#selection").val(regionName);
            
            $("#selection").on('change', function(){
                if ($("#selection").val() === regionName ) {
                  $("#q").click();
                }
              });


  
        },

      });
      

      map.setSelectedRegions( JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem('jvectormap-selected-regions') || '[]' ) );
 
    });

  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <img src={% static "logo-bot.jpg" %} width=100 alt="Logo">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Apps
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="dropdown1">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="dropdown2">Another action</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="dropdown3">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="d-flex" method="POST" action=".">
          

        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="hidden" name="q" value=""/>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
              var states = [
                {% for states in states %}

                " {{states.state}} ",

                {% endfor %}

              ];

              $("#selection").autocomplete({
                  source: states
              }); 

            });

          </script>



          </script>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" name="q">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="wrap">


  <div  class="jvectormap-container" id="map1" style="width: 750px; height: 600px"></div>
```

**Here is the form from views.py:**

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    selection = forms.CharField(label="", widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'"form-control me-2"','id':'selection', 'name':'q', 'placeholder':'  State'}))
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your template?

Comment: @IainShelvington shared